# How to update Jenkins config.xml from Java code?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins Plugin development so pardon me if the question is silly. I am currently developing a Jenkins Plugin that provides a very small list of configuration options as shown in the attached screenshot.

The form has been designed using Jelly script. I have to update these parameters submitted by my form in the config.xml file of the job from my Java Code. Can anyone suggest the way to update the current config.xml of the job in my Java Code?

Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow policy didnt allow me to post images

Comment: In cases like this I would look for an existing plugin that does something similar, and browse the code.  You could also try the Jenkins developer mailing list / Google group.

Comment: Sadly for me, there are no plugins that match my use case mentioned here. I have mailed them. There is this Maven Project Plugin, but it is highly complex to comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have got to know how to update the config file through user defined form.

PFB Code

```
AbstractItem item= (AbstractItem) Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(itemName)
Source streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(config))
item.updateByXml(streamSource);
item.save();
```

In the jelly the form has to called the method like this

```
<f:form method="post" name="config" action="configSubmit">
```

So the code to update has to be placed in the method as follows

```
public void doConfigSubmit(StaplerRequest req, StaplerResponse rsp) throws
IOException, ServletException, Descriptor.FormException
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jenkins-client-api project to access Jenkins from java application.
It is quite standard and definitely of great help when interacting from Java application to Jenkins.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api