# schema for hudson job config.xml

Tags: java, xml, hudson, hudson-api

am new to **HUDSON ci-server** . i have a requirement stating that i have to use Hudson remote access API and create new jobs in hudson or edit the **existing job's configuration file and update it**.

I have a sample **config.xml** file .

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
<actions/>
<description>Free style Basic sample Job for POC . will create this job with all the required fields . then will take this config.xml and will try to validate and study this schema .</description>
<project-properties class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
<entry>
  <string>hudson-plugins-disk_usage-DiskUsageProperty</string>
  <base-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.plugins.disk_usage.DiskUsageProperty"/>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </base-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>logRotator</string>
  <log-rotator-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
      <daysToKeep>5</daysToKeep>
      <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
      <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
      <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </log-rotator-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>scmCheckoutRetryCount</string>
  <integer-property>
    <originalValue class="int">5</originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </integer-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>hudson-tasks-Mailer</string>
  <external-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.tasks.Mailer">
      <recipients>abc@example.com</recipients>
      <dontNotifyEveryUnstableBuild>false</dontNotifyEveryUnstableBuild>
      <sendToIndividuals>false</sendToIndividuals>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
    <modified>true</modified>
  </external-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>hudson-plugins-build_timeout-BuildTimeoutWrapper</string>
  <external-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.plugins.build_timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper">
      <timeoutMinutes>5</timeoutMinutes>
      <failBuild>false</failBuild>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
    <modified>true</modified>
  </external-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>builders</string>
  <describable-list-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.util.DescribableList">
      <hudson.tasks.Ant>
        <targets></targets>
        <antName>org.apache.ant_1.7.1</antName>
      </hudson.tasks.Ant>
      <hudson.tasks.Shell>
        <command>HUDSON_USER</command>
      </hudson.tasks.Shell>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </describable-list-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>hudson-triggers-SCMTrigger</string>
  <trigger-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger">
      <spec>@daily</spec>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </trigger-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>jdk</string>
  <string-property>
    <originalValue class="string">(Inherit From Job)</originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </string-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>hudson-tasks-ArtifactArchiver</string>
  <external-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver">
      <compressionType>GZIP</compressionType>
      <latestOnly>false</latestOnly>
      <autoValidateFileMask>false</autoValidateFileMask>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
    <modified>true</modified>
  </external-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>scm</string>
  <scm-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </scm-property>
</entry>
<entry>
  <string>hudson-plugins-release-ReleaseWrapper</string>
  <external-property>
    <originalValue class="hudson.plugins.release.ReleaseWrapper">
      <releaseVersionTemplate></releaseVersionTemplate>
      <doNotKeepLog>false</doNotKeepLog>
      <overrideBuildParameters>false</overrideBuildParameters>
      <parameterDefinitions/>
      <preBuildSteps/>
      <postBuildSteps/>
      <postSuccessfulBuildSteps/>
      <postFailedBuildSteps/>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
    <modified>true</modified>
  </external-property>
</entry>
</project-properties>
 <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
<creationTime>1403865219075</creationTime>
 <properties/>
     <cascadingChildrenNames class="java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet"/>
     <cascading-job-properties class="java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet">
    <string>hudson-plugins-batch_task-BatchTaskProperty</string>
  <string>hudson-plugins-disk_usage-DiskUsageProperty</string>
  <string>hudson-plugins-jira-JiraProjectProperty</string>
  <string>org-hudsonci-plugins-snapshotmonitor-WatchedDependenciesProperty</string>
  <string>hudson-plugins-promoted_builds-JobPropertyImpl</string>
   </cascading-job-properties>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>false</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <cleanWorkspaceRequired>false</cleanWorkspaceRequired>
 </project>
```

Now i have a tag called project-properties . in it i have multiple **entry** tags .each **enrty** tag has some sub tags among which **string** is common to each **entry** tag .I want to access all these different tags through java using **Hudosn remote access API** .

for example :

```
<entry>
      <string>logRotator</string>
      <log-rotator-property>
      <originalValue class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
      <daysToKeep>5</daysToKeep>
      <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
      <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
      <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
    </originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </log-rotator-property>
</entry>
```

so i want to acceess **daysToKeep numToKeep artifactDaysToKeep** and so on for the rest of  tags and other tags present in the **config.xml**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by getting an instance of the Item and then updating the project configuration by using the following code

```
Source streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(config));
    try {
        proj.updateByXml(streamSource);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PluginImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

the config is the string generated config file.

For more info refer to this post [How to update Jenkins config.xml from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440297/how-to-update-jenkins-config-xml-from-java-code)