# how can i update Jenkins System configuration through java code

Tags: java, configuration, jenkins, hudson

i have certain requirement in which i have to update Jenkins `SystemConfiguration` through Java code. I am trying to update only few parameters which are getting saved in 4 files namely

1. config.xml
2. hudosn.tasks.Maven
3. hudson.tasks.Mailer
4. hudson.tasks.Ant

Can anyone suggest how to do this or any workaround will also be useful ...Thanks in advance

Comment: Try checking this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440297/how-to-update-jenkins-config-xml-from-java-code

Comment: @Pat thanks for the reply . . i saw the link above in that they refer to **StaplerRequest** and **StaplerResponse** ... i went through the internet but din quite get how they can be used .. Can you elaborate a bit on this ... Thanks in advance